# error C2664: 'strcmp' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char' to 'const char *'

Tags: c++, strcmp

I need help about that script.

```
BOOL Checking(LPCSTR MacID) {
    char ClientMacs[18] = { "11:22:33:44:55:66",};

    for(int x=0; x < 10; x++) {
        if(!strcmp(MacID, ClientMacs[x])) {
            printf(MacID," Successed!");
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I'm getting

> error C2664: 'strcmp' : cannot convert
>   parameter 2 from 'char' to 'const char
>   *' Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires
>   reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or
>   function-style cast

when I try to compile it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not

```
if(!strcmp(MacID, ClientMacs[x])) {    }
```

but

```
if(!strcmp(MacID, &ClientMacs[x])) { ... }
```

Arg 2 has to be a char *, but you have it as char. If your arg 2 were plain

```
  ClientMacs  // compiler understands that this is shorthand for &ClientMacs[0]
```

it would be fine. But when the index is other than zero, you have to put the ampersand with it.

-- pete

Comment: Somehow I don't think his real intent was to compare a single character of his array to the string being passed in.

Comment: @Brian -- Somehow I don't think you are wrong. strcmp( ) does not compare a single character, by definition. Why do you think it does? I think he wants to START the multi-char compare at ClientMacs[x] and continue the multi-char compare until strcmp( ) finds a NUL in one or the other string. That's what strcmp( ) does. Who said anything about single-char compares?

Comment: @Pete - He did, by trying to pass `ClientMacs[x]` (A single character) to strcmp (which of course takes a `char*`).  Your changes will make it work, but only by nullifying his loop entirely. The first iteration where you have him pass in `&ClientMacs[0]` will either succeed or fail - it's the same thing as passing `ClientMacs` - it's a pointer to the first byte of the array. His logic only makes sense if he thought he had a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: The dangling `,` in his initial assignment adds additional credence to that theory.

Comment: Sorry - I worded that incorrectly - the point I'm trying to make is there's little logic in doing what you describe. Why would he be trying to find out if the string matched starting somewhere in the first 10 bytes?

Comment: To find a substring that begins at some character offset from theCandidateString[0], he'd start matching at that substring's first character, would he not? For example, if you were interested in matching just the domain name from a URL, you might call strrchr( ) to find the location of the final forward slash in the URL; then call strncmp( ) on the characters following that final forward slash. I do this all the time; but I'm always looking to learn and I'll be glad to hear from you how to beef up the logic of that strategy.

Answer (score 1):

there's and & missing ... non-pointer <-> pointer

```
BOOL Checking(LPCSTR MacID) {

    const char* ClientMacs[18] = { "11:22:33:44:55:66",};

     for(int x=0; x < 10; x++) {

         if(!strcmp(MacID, ClientMacs[x])) {

              printf(MacID," Successed!");

              return true;

         }

    }

    return false;

}
```

perhaps

Comment: dont know, then is crashed windows ask for debuging

Comment: The error is that when x > 0, this code passes a null pointer to `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 1):

ClientMacs needs to be an array of pointers to chars (string pointers), not an array of chars.  You might as well use the LPCSTR typedef, because you've also used it for the function parameter.

Try this:

```
BOOL Checking(LPCSTR MacID) {

    LPCSTR ClientMacs[18] = { "11:22:33:44:55:66", [put the other 9 (or is it 17?) MAC address strings here]};

    for(int x=0; x < 10; x++) {

         if(!strcmp(MacID, ClientMacs[x])) {
            printf(MacID," Successed!");
            return true;
         }
    }
}
```

Your naming is generally pretty horrible, but I haven't changed that.

Comment: @Will -- I'm afraid that what you say is not exactly true. OP doesn't want an array of pointers, but a pointer to somewhere inside the char array ClientMacs[].

Comment: @Pete - I don't think he does. I think that's what he ended up with trying to do what Will outlines above (Note the dangling `,` in his char array assignment and it makes no sense to compare the first 10 characters)

Comment: dodwords:
        mov     eax,[edx]

        cmp     al,[ecx]
        jne     short donene
        or      al,al
        jz      short doneeq
        cmp     ah,[ecx + 1]
        jne     short donene
        or      ah,ah
        jz      short doneeq

        shr     eax,16        ->>> it crash on cmp     al,[ecx]       on file strcmp.asm  using 2005 debug

Comment: I have added an annotation as to where the missing addresses are - I'm 95% sure he's trying to see if the supplied address matches any of a list of possibilities.

Comment: This question is so full of fail (not your reply - that's basically on the money). Note that `!strcmp()` is going to result in the `printf()` being called and returning when the strings *don't* match. Of course you'll never see "Successed" as the `printf()` is wrong as well; it's only going to print the `MacID`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!strcmp(MacID, ClientMacs[x]))
                // ^^^^^^^^^^^ gives the character at index x
```

Probably you meant -

```
if(!strcmp(MacID, &ClientMacs[x]))
                //^  Added & symbol
```

Given the `printf` statement, I think, there is no need to compare character by character. There is no need of loop. This can be -

```
 for(int x=0; x < 10; x++) {
    if(!strcmp(MacID, ClientMacs[x])) {
        printf(MacID," Successed!");
        return true;
    }
}
```

condensed to -

```
if(!strcmp(MacID, ClientMacs)) {  // Changed ClientMacs[x] to ClientMacs
    printf(MacID," Successed!");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're quite understanding how strings (or pointers) work in C.

You are trying to compare a single character of your character array to the string being passed in:

```
if(!strcmp(MacID, ClientMacs[x])
```

Comment: strcmp( ) doesn't work here. For a one-char compare, do this:

Comment: if ( MacID[x] == ClientMacs[x] ) { ... } or similar.

Comment: That was my point, Pete. Will Dean has the correct answer. Unfortunately the poor guy will probably never see it (Though he might come back when he tries to assign `{ "<mac address>", "<mac address>" }` to his character array).

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged this C++, I'd advise against using `strcmp` at all, and use `std::string` instead:

```
std::set<std::string> ClientMacs;

ClientMacs.insert("11:22:33:44:55:66");
 // presumably insert more MAC addresses here


bool check(std::string const &MacID) {    
    if (ClientMacs.find(MacID) != ClienMacs.end()) {
        std::cout << "Success!";
        return true;
    }
}
```

I should add, however, that it's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish here. My assumption is that you have a list of possible MAC addresses (e.g., of all the computers in your local network) and you're trying to verify that a MAC address you've received (e.g., in an Ethernet packet) matches one of those (e.g., for something on the order of a firewall that will ensure that only packets from known sources are accepted).